# Laravel File Upload, Allowed memory of size x exceeded but worked last week

Tags: php, laravel

Im working on a project that is being hosted on a digitalocean droplet. This droplet is running on PHP7.4 with nginx. When i initially setup the droplet and deployed the laravel project it ran perfectly. The file upload within the project worked as expected and there were no issues.

Now suddenly the file upload has stopped working and i get the following error message:

```
Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 57590561 bytes)
```

After looking into the issue, debugging and searching for a solution on the web i still cant figure out why this error occurs.

The settings in the php.ini are configured like this:

```
memory_limit => 2048M => 2048M
post_max_size => 200M => 200M
upload_max_filesize => 200M => 200M
```

The memory_limit might be overkill i know that but i tried to change it to check if that would fix my issue.

The code that is used to upload the file to my azure blob storage works like this:

```
 $dateTime = Carbon::now();
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $filePath = $request->machine. '/' .$dateTime.$file->getClientOriginalName();
        Storage::disk('azure')->put($filePath, file_get_contents($file));

        $document = Document::get()
            ->where('machine_id', '=', $request->machine)
            ->where('name', '=', $file->getClientOriginalName());

        $version = $document->max('version') + 1;

        if($document == null)
        {
            $document = new Document();
            $document->machine_id = $request->machine;
            $document->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $document->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $document->path = $filePath;
            $document->version = 1;
            $document->uploaded = $dateTime;
            $document->save();
        } else {
            $document = new Document();
            $document->machine_id = $request->machine;
            $document->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $document->name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $document->path = $filePath;
            $document->version = $version;
            $document->uploaded = $dateTime;

            $document->save();
        }
```

Like i explained earlier, this code might not be the best at the moment but it works on my environment and used to run on the production environment.

Can someone explain why this issue occurs and how i might fix it?

Comment: Have you restarted the `php7.4-fpm` service since updating the php configuration values?

Comment: Yes, i did. Did not change anything tho

Comment: Can you run your code again but with `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` added to the PHP file causing the issue.

Comment: Also, just confirming you are modifying the correct `php.ini` file, which based on your question, I would assume is located at `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`?

Comment: @RJK After checking the loaded configuration i found that the loaded php.ini is located at /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini. I modified that one.

Comment: That configuration file is for when php is invoked through the command line, since you are using nginx I would expect you to be using PHP-FPM, which has a different configuration file. If you create a new route in Laravel and run the `phpinfo()` function, then find `Loaded Configuration File`, what is it's value?

Comment: Wont this command do the same? php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'

Comment: When executing PHP in different environments, a separate configuration file is loaded. When running php from the command line the configuration file `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini` is loaded, but when executing php within the context of a web server (in this scenario its nginx, which most likely uses PHP-FPM) a different `php.ini` file is loaded and chances are it's located at `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`. Therefore, since `php -i | grep 'Loaded Configuration File'` is invoking php from the `cli` (Command Line Interface) it will be reading its configuration data from `/etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini`.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, i checked the php.ini in the fpm path and changed the setting to match the other file. THe upload start but quits at 60% then gives me the same error message.

Comment: Did you restart the `php7.4-fpm` service after changing the values? e.g. `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

Comment: Yes i updated the file, restarted the fpm service and then tried again. Could it be that the memory_limit that is set to 2048M might be configured in the wrong way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228250/discussion-between-rjk-and-collin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [discussing the issue](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228250/discussion-between-rjk-and-collin), the issue was that there was an additional `.ini` configuration file that was being scanned which was overwriting the changes made to the configuration file located at `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`.

The issue was fixed by simply increasing the allowed memory limit.

For anyone else that experiences this issue you can add the following route to Laravel which will show all PHP configuration values:

```
Route::get('/phpinfo', function() {
    phpinfo();
});
```

Then navigate to `/phpinfo` and you will then be able to debug the issue.

In this particular instance the issue was that there were `.ini` files that existed under the scan directory, this directory can be found by looking up the value `Scan this dir for additional .ini files` from the result of the `phpinfo()` function.

**Make sure that this route is removed before pushing the code into production as it can be used to help further aid attackers.**

As stated in the discussion that this does fix OP's issue at this moment in time, but simply increasing the allowed memory limit is not best practice as there is an underlying issue with the code which is causing it to exceed the memory limit, which may happen again in the future.